# No output after using strcmp()

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user to input a string then checks to see how many vowels and consonants are in the string, using c strings. Right now I'm working on the function that counts the vowels. I finally got it to were I don't have any errors, but my program just hangs up after choosing to count the vowels. Here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class VowelsandConsonants {

public:
int findVowels(char *cString, const int STRINGLEN) {
    const int SIZE = STRINGLEN;
    int vowelCount = 0;

    char *str = cString;
    char vowels[5] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        str[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; i++) {
            vowels[j];
            if (strcmp(vowels, str)) {
                vowelCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    return vowelCount;
}


};

int main()
{
char *myString = nullptr;
const int STRLEN = 20;
int selection;

myString = new char[STRLEN];

VowelsandConsonants v;

cout << "Enter a string 20 characters or less." << endl;
cin.getline(myString, STRLEN);

cout << "Select the number of what you want to do." << endl;
cout << "1.) Count the number of vowels." << endl;
cout << "2.) Count the number of consonants." << endl;
cout << "3.) Count both vowels and consonants." << endl;
cout << "4.) Enter another string." << endl;
cout << "5.) Exit program." << endl;

cin >> selection;

if (selection == 1) {
    cout << v.findVowels(myString, STRLEN);
}


delete[] myString;

return 0;
}
```

Am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: What do you  think that statements like `str[i];` are doing?

Comment: I thought it would iterate through the characters.

Comment: Why would you think that? What C++ textbook that you are using has code like that in it?

Comment: I wouldn't use a class to contain a single function.  Since the functionality is small, either place into a free standing function or in the `main` function.

Comment: Save yourself some pain, use `std::string` instead of C-Style arrays.

Comment: I don't know. I'm having a hard time learning how to do some of this.

Comment: @Thomas I wish I could. It's a requirement for the assignment.

Comment: Looks like you followed from bad examples and didn't know it, as Neil suggested, because writing code that wrong takes years of willful ignorance on someone's part.

Comment: Functions can only return one object, so you will either need two functions or some other data structure for returning both vowel quantity and consonent quantity.

Comment: @Thomas I am aware of that. I haven't got to the consonant function yet. Once I know how to get this one working I'll move on to the next function.

Comment: You need to rethink your code. The statement `vowels[j];` does nothing, and `vowels` is not a null-terminated string, so calling `strcmp()` on it results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I recommend using a C-Style string containing the vowels, then using `strchr` to search it:

```
const char vowels[] = "aeiou";
const size_t length = strlen(cString);
unsigned int vowel_count = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    if (strchr(vowels, cString[i]) != NULL)
    {
        ++vowel_count;
    }
}
```

There are other methods, such as using an array to hold the counts (and using the letter as an index) or `std::map`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Don't know why this was downvoted, it works great. Glad there are some programmers out there that are willing to help and not insult.

Comment: Life would be nice if downvoters would leave a comment.

Comment: So, are the C-Style strings not C++?  Last time I checked, they were allowed.  Also, the OP is not allowed to use `std::string`.

Comment: @Aluan C-Strings are apart of C++. The C++ string library is built on top of C-Strings. The requirements are to use C-Strings. People like you shouldn't be apart of this community.

Comment: @KennyFreeman I don't care about your requirements. Your teacher is wrong. He is teaching you poorly. Furthermore Stack Overflow is not a homework writing service. C-Strings are there, yes and so are raw pointers. You should use neither. Your program uses `new` and `delete` in a non RAII context. If an exception is thrown you will leak memory and there's nothing you can do about it except to fix the fundamental mistake of using the wrong techniques, and not learning abstractions.

Comment: @Aluan We are learning that C-Strings aren't used often. However, it is still important to know how to use them, and understand how they work. An answer shouldn't be down voted because of your opinion. Also I'm not using it to "write" my homework. I had an issue with one part of my code. I'm not asking someone to write the program for me. I'm sure you never needed help to learn a concept, right?

Comment: @KennyFreeman no it is not important to learn them. Find me a C# course that starts by teaching you to use `char*` for strings? (The language has them) Also using `new` and `delete` in that manner (no RAII) is categorically wrong. It is always wrong and will always be wrong.

Comment: So we should learn to code without knowing how things work behind the scenes? The book we are using is from 2017. So, I'm pretty sure there is still some logic in coding this way. Regardless, his answer didn't have anything to do with using new and delete. Yet you still down voted out of spite.

Comment: @Aluan Your right my teacher is lazy. However, we are learning from the book. The teacher hasn't shown me anything. I just looked into what RAII is and that is what we are learning from the book. We are told to clear the heap in a destructor whenever possible. However, in a program this small I didn't find it necessary. Maybe I'm wrong on that, but I'm still learning. The point still stands that you down voted an answer for no reason. You logic was that the question was about C++. Now your argument is about my code which has nothing to do with his answer.

Comment: @KennyFreeman at least your book introduces RAII. My text books and none of my teachers touched the subject. I had to spend a long time unlearning all the crap I have been taught, how to write code that could not by definition ever be bug free.

Comment: @Aluan So what resources did you use to learn to program the right way?

Comment: Regarding the answer it is bad. He's told you how to do your homework not how to improve your code, and not how to learn anything. Hell he's even using the `NULL` macro and that alone is worth a downvote. Anyway I advise you to use `std::string` which has a `find` method. `if (vowels.find(myString[i])) {...}` is clear, clean, and obvious.

Comment: I taught myself by watching lectures by the creator of the language, who by the way is a teacher, reading his books, and by watching lectures and reading articles by professionals working for companies like Microsoft, Id Software, Apple, etc. I have a long way to go, especially since most of the jobs are in web development where I live, but I did manage to learn some fundamentally important aspects of C++, that all of these people agree on and why they agree. I also managed to learn something about the fallacy of education system. Also 1 good teacher, who wasn't in CS dept, but simulation dept

Comment: I'll try it out after I finish this other assignment.

Comment: To be fair, there were some other fairly good teachers but most of them went by the text books. In my case those books were worse than yours. This was a four-year University with a good reputation.